# How to compute percentile for an external element with given array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, percentile

I'm looking for a percentile function that accepts an array and an element where it would return closest percentile of the element.

Some examples

```
percentile([1,2,3,4,5], 2) => 40% 
percentile([1,2,3,4,5], 2.5) => 40% 
percentile([1,2,3,4,5], 6) => 100%
```

Does anything like this or similar exist within python or numpy?

Numpy does this `np.percentile(a=[1,2,3,4,5], q=3) => 1.12` which is not desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.percentile(a, q)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) tells you the `q`th percentile in the `a` array. This is the inverse of what you want. I don't think numpy has a function to do what you want, but it's easy enough to make your own.

The percentile tells you the percentage of elements of the array that are smaller than the given element, so just do that:

```
def percentile(lst: list, val) -> float:
    return sum(i <= val for i in lst) / len(lst)
```

If you have a numpy array, you don't need to iterate over it since `<=` will broadcast over the array:

```
def percentile(arr: np.ndarray, val) -> float:
    return np.mean(arr <= val) # thanks Chrysophylaxs!
    # return (arr <= val).sum() / len(arr)
```

```
>>> percentile([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
# 0.4
>>> percentile([1,2,3,4,5], 2.5)
# 0.4
>>> percentile([1,2,3,4,5], 6)
# 1.0
```

Comment: `np.mean(arr <= val)` for the numpy variant

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs of course! I'm going to blame that brain fart on having to deal with the entire family over the holidays ;)